# Error install FIA Project Management Plugin

Tags: fiware

I tried to install FIA Project Management Plugin as instructions in the Eclipse Luna but I get errors dependence and plugin not installed There is any person who installed it? thanks

This is the error when i try install the plug-in Eclipse Luna

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found. Software being installed: FI-WARE FI-CoDE FIA Project
>   Management Plugin 0.1.0.201402071124
>   (eu.fiware.ficode.fia.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201402071124)
>   Missing requirement: Mylyn FusionForge Connector Core
>   1.1.0.201402071124 (eu.fiware.ficode.mylyn.fusionforge.core 1.1.0.201402071124) requires 'package org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.soap 0.0.0' but it
>   could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Fia Project
>   Creation Wizard 0.2.0.201402071124 (eu.fiware.ficode.fia
>   0.2.0.201402071124) To: bundle eu.fiware.ficode.mylyn.fusionforge.core 1.1.0 Cannot satisfy dependency: From: FI-WARE FI-CoDE FIA Project Management Plugin 0.1.0.201402071124
>   (eu.fiware.ficode.fia.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201402071124) To:
>   eu.fiware.ficode.fia [0.2.0.201402071124]

---

This is the error when i try install the plug-in Eclipse Luna
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: FI-WARE FI-CoDE FIA Project Management Plugin 0.1.0.201402071124 (eu.fiware.ficode.fia.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201402071124)
  Missing requirement: Mylyn FusionForge Connector Core 1.1.0.201402071124 (eu.fiware.ficode.mylyn.fusionforge.core 1.1.0.201402071124) requires 'package org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.soap 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Fia Project Creation Wizard 0.2.0.201402071124 (eu.fiware.ficode.fia 0.2.0.201402071124)
    To: bundle eu.fiware.ficode.mylyn.fusionforge.core 1.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: FI-WARE FI-CoDE FIA Project Management Plugin 0.1.0.201402071124 (eu.fiware.ficode.fia.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201402071124)
    To: eu.fiware.ficode.fia [0.2.0.201402071124]

Comment: Can you please explain what errors you get and be specific with your question.

Comment: This is the error that i have

Answer (score 0):

The FI-WARE FI-CoDE FIA Project Management Plugin was implemented for Eclipse Indigo. No new updates of this plugin have been released supporting recent Eclipse releases, therefore you can only install it on this version. Besides, you need to install the Fusion Forge Connector, and the FI-CoDE Wizards for Fusion Forge User/Project Management, as explained in [1]
The error you help precisely indicates a missing dependency for Mylyn FusionForge Connector Core. Have a look to [2] for instructions to install the Fusion Forge Connector before installing this plugin on Indigo.

Hope this helps

[1] https://forge.fiware.org/frs/download.php/451/FICoDE_FIA_Project_Management_User_Manual_0.2.0.pdf

[2] http://forge.fiware.org/frs/download.php/112/FusionForge_Connector_User_Manual_1.1.0.pdf